# Django-How to create a field based on another field in the same model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a field for each Person that stores the pinyin (translate Chinese characters into letters) of that person's name,  using function `pinyin()`(which is working and tested). But I can't seem to create the field `name_pinyin` based on the name field in the same model. Is this the correct way to approaching this problem? Thanks in advance

```
from django.db import models
from xpinyin import Pinyin

class Person(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length500)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_pinyin = models.CharField(pinyin(name)，max_length = 200)

    def pinyin(self):
        p=Pinyin()
        return p.get_Pinyin()(str(self),'') 
    #This is a function that returns pinyin of chinese characters
```

Comment: Do you need to save `name_pinyin` into the database? Could you instead just call `get_Pinyin()` everytime the pinyin version of the name is needed?

Comment: Yes I think that should work too, thanks！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the model save method like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length500)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_pinyin = models.CharField(pinyin(name)，max_length = 200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name_pinyin = Pinyin(self.name)
        super(Person, self).save()
```